# Склонение слов в плагине JS

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

есть вот такой JS плагин таймера:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.downCount = function (options, callback) {
    var settings = $.extend({
            date: null,
            offset: null
        }, options);

    if (!settings.date) {
        $.error('Date is not defined.');
    }

    if (!Date.parse(settings.date)) {
        $.error('Incorrect date format, it should look like this, 12/24/2017 12:00:00.');
    }

    var container = this;

    var secCount = -1;
    var minCount = -1;

    var timeZone = +0;  
    if($('#timer').attr('data-date-timezone') && ($('#timer').attr('data-date-timezone') != '')){
        timeZone = $('#timer').attr('data-date-timezone');
    }

    var currentDate = function () {

        var date = new Date();

        var utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) - (360000*100) +(360000*10)*timeZone;

        var new_date = new Date(utc + (3600000*settings.offset))

        return new_date;
    };

    function countdown () {
        var target_date = new Date(settings.date),
            current_date = currentDate();

        var difference = target_date - current_date;

        if (difference < 0) {

            clearInterval(interval);

            if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback();

            return;
        }

        var _second = 1000,
            _minute = _second * 60,
            _hour = _minute * 60,
            _day = _hour * 24;
        var _centi = _second / 100;

        var days = Math.floor(difference / _day),
            hours = Math.floor((difference % _day) / _hour),
            minutes = Math.floor((difference % _hour) / _minute),
            seconds = Math.floor((difference % _minute) / _second),
            centis = Math.floor((difference % _minute) / _centi );

            days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : '0' + days;
            hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : '0' + hours;
            minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : '0' + minutes;
            seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : '0' + seconds;

        var ref_days = (days === 1) ? 'day' : 'days',
            ref_hours = (hours === 1) ? 'hour' : 'hours',
            ref_minutes = (minutes === 1) ? 'minute' : 'minutes',
            ref_seconds = (seconds === 1) ? 'second' : 'seconds';
        if(centis == 0){
            centis = 6000;
        }
        if(seconds == 0){
            seconds = 60;
        }
        if(seconds%60 == 0){                
            secCount--;
        }

        if(minutes == 0){
            minutes = 60;
        }
        if((minutes%60 == 0) && (seconds == 59)){                
            minCount--;
        }

        container.find('#days').text(days);
        container.find('#hours').text(hours);
        container.find('#minutes').text(minutes);
        container.find('#seconds').text(seconds);

    };

    var interval = setInterval(countdown, 333.333);

};

})(jQuery);
```

Есть HTML разметка:

```
<ul class="timer" id="timer" data-date="2018-06-06 18:00:00" data-date-timezone="+3">
    <li><span id="hours">00</span>Часы</li>
    <li class="dots">:</li>
    <li><span id="minutes">00</span>Минуты</li>
    <li class="dots">:</li>
    <li><span id="seconds">00</span>Секунды</li>
</ul>
```

И есть функция вызова:

```
$(function() {

    $('#timer').downCount({
        date: $('#timer').attr('data-date'),
        offset: +10
    });

});
```

Я полагаю в этом плагине уже реализована функция склонения слов.

К примеру:
1 день, 2 дня или 2 часа, 11 часов

Помогите разобраться как ее подключить к HTML. Сам таймер работает а вот с клонением слов возникли проблемы!

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, функция реализована, но англоязычная и нужно было дописать вывод в ваш элемент. Вообще для решения таких задач я бы посоветовал использовать moment.js и не писать лишний раз велосипед со своими костылями в колёсах, к нему также можно подключить множество локалей, включая и русскую.

```js
$.fn.downCount = function(options, callback) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    date: null,
    offset: null
  }, options);

  if (!settings.date) {
    $.error('Date is not defined.');
  }

  if (!Date.parse(settings.date)) {
    $.error('Incorrect date format, it should look like this, 12/24/2017 12:00:00.');
  }

  var container = this;

  var secCount = -1;
  var minCount = -1;

  var timeZone = +0;
  if ($('#timer').attr('data-date-timezone') && ($('#timer').attr('data-date-timezone') != '')) {
    timeZone = $('#timer').attr('data-date-timezone');
  }

  var currentDate = function() {

    var date = new Date();

    var utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) - (360000 * 100) + (360000 * 10) * timeZone;

    var new_date = new Date(utc + (3600000 * settings.offset))

    return new_date;
  };

  function countdown() {
    var target_date = new Date(settings.date),
      current_date = currentDate();

    var difference = target_date - current_date;

    if (difference < 0) {

      clearInterval(interval);

      if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback();

      return;
    }

    var _second = 1000,
      _minute = _second * 60,
      _hour = _minute * 60,
      _day = _hour * 24;
    var _centi = _second / 100;

    var days = Math.floor(difference / _day),
      hours = Math.floor((difference % _day) / _hour),
      minutes = Math.floor((difference % _hour) / _minute),
      seconds = Math.floor((difference % _minute) / _second),
      centis = Math.floor((difference % _minute) / _centi);

    days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : '0' + days;
    hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : '0' + hours;
    minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : '0' + minutes;
    seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : '0' + seconds;

    var ref_days = (days === 1) ? 'day' : 'days',
      ref_hours = (hours === 1) ? 'hour' : 'hours',
      ref_minutes = (minutes === 1) ? 'minute' : 'minutes',
      ref_seconds = (seconds === 1) ? 'second' : 'seconds';
    if (centis == 0) {
      centis = 6000;
    }
    if (seconds == 0) {
      seconds = 60;
    }
    if (seconds % 60 == 0) {
      secCount--;
    }

    if (minutes == 0) {
      minutes = 60;
    }
    if ((minutes % 60 == 0) && (seconds == 59)) {
      minCount--;
    }

    container.find('#days').text(days + ref_days);
    container.find('#hours').text(hours + ref_hours);
    container.find('#minutes').text(minutes + ref_minutes);
    container.find('#seconds').text(seconds + ref_seconds);

  };

  var interval = setInterval(countdown, 333.333);

};

$(function() {

  $('#timer').downCount({
    date: $('#timer').attr('data-date'),
    offset: +10
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timer" id="timer" data-date="2018-06-06 18:00:00" data-date-timezone="+3">
  <li><span id="hours"></span></li>
  <li class="dots">:</li>
  <li><span id="minutes"></span></li>
  <li class="dots">:</li>
  <li><span id="seconds"></span></li>
</ul>
```